# How to filter a wordpress search by taxonomy terms?

Tags: wordpress, search, taxonomy

I have a custom post type named *projects* and a taxonomy named *type* and some terms of that taxonomy like *research*, *work*, *personal* in which a project can belong or not. I want to create a wordpress custom search for *projects* and a dropdown menu with all the terms of my taxonomy.

In order to select only *projects* I was thinking to use something like this in my *function.php* file:

```
function SearchFilter($query) {
   if ($query->is_search) {
      $query->set('post_type', 'projects');
   }
   return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');
```

And to create a dropdown menu with *type* taxonomy terms I was thinking to use something like this in my *searchform.php* file:

```
<label for="type">Type:</label>
<select id="type" name="type">
   <?php $project_types = get_categories('taxonomy=type'); ?>
   <option value="">All</option>
   <?php foreach ($project_types as $project_type) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $project_type->term_id; ?>">
         <?php echo $project_type->name; ?>
      </option>
   <?php } ?>
</select>
```

They work individually but I don't know how to make them work together! I don't know how to handle the variable passed through the form into the function SearchFilter.

Thank you in advance for help!

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this, let's say that we have a custom post type called "*podcast*" which has a custom taxonomy attached to it called "*season*". What we want to do is order the "*podcast*" posts by "*season*".

So first of all we need to get all the terms of "*season*" and order them by name, then we need to loop through the seasons, inside the seasons loop we have to get the podcast posts that belong to the current season and finally loop through them.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
// get the seasons term
$seasons = get_terms(array(
   'taxonomy'   => 'season',
   'orderby' => 'name',
   'order' => 'DESC',
));

// if $seasons exists loop through seasons
if ($seasons) :
  foreach ($seasons as $season) :

    // query podcasts based on current season
    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'podcast',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'orderby' => 'DATE',
      'tax_query' => [
        [
          'taxonomy' => 'season',
          'field' => 'slug',
          'terms' => $season->slug,
        ]
      ],
    );

    $podcasts = new WP_Query($args);

    // loop through the podcasts
    if ($podcasts->have_posts()) : ?>
      <div class="podcast-season-wrapper" data-season="<?= $season->slug ?>">
        <h2 class="podcasts-season-title"><?= $season->name ?></h2>
        <?php
        while ($podcasts->have_posts()) : $podcasts->the_post();
          get_template_part('template-partials/posts/podcast-loop', null, ['season' => $season]);
        endwhile; ?>
      </div><?php
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
  endforeach;
endif;
```

Answer (score -1):

I know it might be outdated, but I was Googling something similar and found a solution to your/our question here:
http://fearlessflyer.com/how-to-create-an-advanced-search-form-for-wordpress/

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.